# How to convert a "formatted double(String)" to double?

Tags: java, jformattedtextfield

I have the following code :

```
 NumberFormat nf=NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
   nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
    String  s=  nf.format(3456.32);
//   double d= Double.valueOf(s); error here
    System.out.println(s);
```

This code displays :

```
3 456,320
```

it's good until now, but imagine when I get the same format from a JFormattedTextField, how I can transform a "3 456,320" as a String to double(3456.32) ?

I have already tried this :

```
String s="3 456,320";
double d= Double.valueOf(s);
```

but i get an error...

**EDIT**:

after several tests, I found the code is not so robust ,for example :

```
 //this works
 String s="3456,6567";

 NumberFormat nf1=NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

 double d = (double) nf1.parse(s);
```

but this one:

```
 String s="3456,0";

 NumberFormat nf1=NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

 double d = (double) nf1.parse(s);
```

I get this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

by cons I find this very robust:

```
    double d = nf1.parse(s).doubleValue();
```

we must test the software several times !!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `NumberFormat` again.

```
NumberFormat nf=NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
String s = "3 456,320";
double d = nf.parse(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

this might work:

```
Double d = Double.valueOf("3 456,320".replace(" ", "").replace(",", "."));
```

(must admit, bit dirty)